# os.makedirs leads to OSError on Amazon AWS Ubuntu instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

On an Ubuntu AWS instance, I am trying to set up a Flask service after setting up Apache.

In `/var/www/html/myApp/`, I have these files, among others:

`myApp.py`

`myApp.wsgi`

Here are the contents of `myApp.wsgi`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/myApp')

from myApp import app as application
```

And here are the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    WSGIDaemonProcess charter threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myApp/myApp.wsgi

    <Directory flaskapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup myApp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And in `myApp.py`, I have some code to make a directory:

```
if not os.path.exists("dir"):
    os.makedirs("dir")
```

But when I navigate my browser to `http://MY-UBUNTU-EC2-ADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myApp/`, it returns a 500 error.

When I check the error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I see these lines:

```
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346698 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792] mod_wsgi (pid=6641): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/myApp/myApp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346734 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792] mod_wsgi (pid=6641): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/myApp/myApp.wsgi'.
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346750 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346768 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792]   File "/var/www/html/myApp/myApp.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346791 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792]     from myApp import app as application
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346797 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792]   File "/var/www/html/myApp/myApp.py", line 12, in <module>
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346806 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792]     os.makedirs(graphicsFiles)
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346811 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346820 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792]     mkdir(name, mode)
[Mon Aug 14 22:57:06.346837 2017] [:error] [pid 6641:tid 139812646708992] [client IP-ADDRESS-REMOVED:48792] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dir'
```

What do I need to change to ensure my app has permission to make a directory or file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use relative path names, nor use a directory which the Apache user can't write to. See documentation at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user

Your Apache configuration is also wrong.

```
<Directory flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup myApp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Using `flaskapp` as argument here to `Directory` isn't correct. That argument should be the directory the WSGI script file is located in.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/myApps>
    WSGIProcessGroup myApp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

A further issues is that it is bad practice to put your source code under the directory specified by `DocumentRoot`. If you were to make a mistake in your Apache configuration, people could download your source code, possibly including any configuration secrets in the source code.

Comment: Thanks. I still get the same error after replacing my typo with `/var/www/html/myApp`. I also tried changing ownership of the `myapp/` directory, and its files, to user `www-data`. Same error.

Comment: Did you change ``os.makedirs("dir")``.? As I said, and the documentation tells you, you cannot use a relative path name. That path would likely resolve to ``/dir``, which you will not have write access to. Calculate it, or set it, as a full absolute path, not a relative path.